# Button does not work on page load

Tags: jquery, html

So I have these buttons working with jQuery, they are working fine except the first one. But when another button is clicked and then the first button is clicked then they do work. So it seems only the first button wont work on a page reload. My toughts where that it has to do with jQuery not being loaded properly.

Any help is much welcome, thanks !

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Boekingsfilter</title>       

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OrganicTabs/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../pagina_1/new.css"> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JqueryUI/js/ui.js"></script>         
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="OrganicTabs/js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>
 </head>

<div id="page-wrap">
    <h1 class="font">Boekingsfilter</h1>        

    <div id="example-one">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="a"><a href="#medewerker" class="current">Medewerker</a></li>
            <li class="b"><a href="#datum_overboeking" class="current">Datum overboeking</a></li>                                              
            <li class="c"><a href="#juliete_geinformeerd" class="current">Juliette geinformeerd</a></li>
            <li class="d"><a href="#boekingsnummer" class="current">Boekingsnummer</a></li>
            <li class="e"><a href="#land" class="current">Land</a></li>
            <li class="f"><a href="#huiscode" class="current">Huiscode</a></li>
            <li class="g"><a href="#aanbieder" class="current">Aanbieder</a></li><br><br><br>
            <li class="h"><a href="#contractvorm" class="current">Contractvorm</a></li>
            <li class="i"><a href="#huursom" class="current">Huursom</a></li>
            <li class="j"><a href="#periode_van" class="current">Periode van</a></li>
            <li class="k"><a href="#periode_tot" class="current">Periode tot</a></li>
            <li class="l"><a href="#distributiekanaal" class="current">Distributiekanaal</a></li>
            <li class="m"><a href="#naam_klant" class="current">Naam klant</a></li>
            <li class="n"><a href="#reden" class="current">Reden</a></li><br><br><br>
            <li class="o"><a href="#nieuwe_boeking" class="current">Nieuwe boeking</a></li>
            <li class="p"><a href="#reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" class="current">Reden geen nieuwe boeking</a></li>
            <li class="q"><a href="#boete_aanbieden" class="current">Boete aanbieden</a></li>
            <li class="r"><a href="#administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" class="current">Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</a></li>
            <li class="s"><a href="#bedrag_van_boete" class="current">Bedrag van boete</a></li>
            <li class="t"><a href="#coulance_happyhome" class="current">Coulance Happyhome</a></li>
            <li class="u"><a href="#opmerking" class="current">Opmerking</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="list-wrap">
        <ul id="medewerker" class="hide">               
            <li><label for="medewerker"><h4>Medewerker</h4></label><br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker">Charlene<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker1">Ellen<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker2">Esmeralda<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker3">Lieke<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker4">Mandy<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker5">Manon<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker6">Samantha<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker7">Sonja<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker8">Susan<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker9">Susanne<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="medewerker" name="medewerker10">Simone<br></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="datum_overboeking" class="hide">             
            <li><label for="datum_overboeking"><h4>Datum overboeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input id="date3" type="text" name="datum_overboeking" value="<?php echo $datum_overboeking; ?>" /></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="juliete_geinformeerd" class="hide">               
            <li><label for="juliete_geinformeerd"><h4>Juliette geinformeerd</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="juliette_geinformeerd" name="juliette_geinformeerd1">ja<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="juliette_geinformeerd" name="juliette_geinformeerd2">nee</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="boekingsnummer" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Boekingsnummer</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer" onkeyup="lookup2(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList2"></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="land" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="land"><h4>Land</h4></label>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land1">Nederland<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land2">België<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land3">Duitsland<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land4">Frankrijk<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land5">Hongarije<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land6">Italië<br></li>          
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land7">Kroatië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land8">Luxemburg<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land9">Oostenrijk<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land10">Slovenië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land11">Spanje<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land12">Tsjechië<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="land" name="land13">Zwitserland<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="huiscode" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>huiscode</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="huiscode" size="20" id="huiscode" onkeyup="lookup5(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions5" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList5"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="aanbieder" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="aanbieder"><h4>Aanbieder</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder1">Agent<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder2">Camping<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder3">Park<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="aanbieder" name="aanbieder4">Particulier<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="contractvorm" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="contractvorm"><h4>Contractvorm</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm1">Aanvraag<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm2">Exclusiviteit<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="contractvorm" name="contractvorm3">Prioriteit<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="huursom" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>huursom</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="huursom" size="20" id="huursom" onkeyup="lookup6(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions6" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList6"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="periode_van" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="periode_van"><h4>Periode van</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="periode_van" name="periode_van"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="periode_tot" class="hide">
            <li><label for="periode_tot"><h4>Periode tot</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="periode_tot" name="periode_tot"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="distributiekanaal" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Distributiekanaal</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="distributiekanaal" onkeyup="lookup4(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions4" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList4"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="naam_klant" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Naam klant</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="reden" class="hide">
            <li><label for="reden"><h4>Reden</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden1">Agent mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden2">Agent mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden3">Calamities ( can not rent) Sale<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden4">Contract is not extended<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden5">Create Double allotment in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden6">Exit<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden7">HappyHome mistake blokking not all<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden8">HappyHome mistake blokking to late in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden9">Other<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden10">Park/Camping mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden11">Park/Camping mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden12">Privat owner mistake did not block in LandLord<br></li>                 
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden13">Privat owner mistake did not informed HappyHome about EV<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden14">Stamgasten (regular guests)<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden15">Itea<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden16">Price is not correct misstake owner<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden17">Inkoper niet juiste contractform aangehouden<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden" name="reden18">To many people<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nieuwe_boeking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="nieuwe_boeking"><h4>Nieuwe boeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking1">No<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking2">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="nieuwe_boeking" name="nieuwe_boeking3">Not Yet<br></li>
        </ul>             

        <ul id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking"><h4>Reden geen nieuwe boeking</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking1">Guest did booked somewhere else<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking2">No good alternative in that area<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking3">Guest did not response<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking" name="reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking4">Otherwhise ….. Fillin true -> Esmeralda<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="boete_aanbieden" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="boete_aanbieden"><h4>Boete aanbieden</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="boete_aanbieden" name="boete_aanbieden1">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="boete_aanbieden" name="boete_aanbieden2">No<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete"><h4>Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete1">Yes<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete2">No<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete" name="administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete3">Not yet<br></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="bedrag_van_boete" class="hide">                
            <li><label>Bedrag van boete</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="bedrag_van_boete" size="20" id="bedrag_van_boete" onkeyup="lookup3(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList3"></li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="coulance_happyhome" class="hide">                                
            <li><label for="coulance_happyhome"><h4>Coulance Happyhome</h4></label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome1">Coulance Agent<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome2">Coulance Camping<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome3">Coulance Park<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome4">Coulance Privatowner<br></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome5">Coulance HappyHome<br></li>   
        </ul>

        <ul id="opmerking" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Opmerking</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="opmerking" size="20" id="opmerking" onkeyup="lookup7(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions7" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList7"></li>
        </ul>      
        </div>
    </div>

<table id="employees">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th>Medewerker</th>
            <th>Datum overboeking</th>
            <th>Juliette geinformeerd</th>
            <th>Boekingsnummer</th>
            <th>Land</th>
            <th>Huiscode</th>
            <th>Aanbieder</th>
            <th>Contractvorm</th>
            <th>Huursom</th>
            <th>Periode van</th>
            <th>Periode tot</th>
            <th>Distributiekanaal</th>
            <th>Naam klant</th>
            <th>Reden</th>
            <th>Nieuwe boeking</th>
            <th>Reden geen nieuwe boeking</th>
            <th>Boete aanbieden</th>
            <th>Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete</th>
            <th>Bedrag van boete</th>
            <th>Coulance Happyhome</th>
            <th>Opmerking</th>
            <th>Id</th>                
        </thead>
    </tr>
</table>                    
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Button does not work'?

Comment: Firstly, please show your jQuery code. Secondly you appear to be loading `jquery-ui` *before* `jquery` itself, which will cause you problems.

Comment: When I change the order of the scripts then the jQuery stops working completely.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include jQuery before jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JqueryUI/js/ui.js"></script>         
<script src="OrganicTabs/js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I change the order of the scripts then the jQuery stops working completely.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery should be loaded first

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="OrganicTabs/js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user3541335: can you post the code in jsfiddle? that way i can see and tell you the fix.

Comment: When I change the order of the scripts then the jQuery stops working completely.

Comment: @user3541335: can you send me the url of the page if it is in public domian? or can you add your code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Also try loading jquery ui from google-api. I have edited my answer for it.

Comment: I copied your order of scripts but it doesnt solve the issue. I tryed to use jsfiddle but I cant put in my php code in it.

Comment: is the application accessible using some url?

Answer (score 0):

Respect the order and add http to the google hosted libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JqueryUI/js/ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I change the order of the scripts then the jQuery stops working completely.